# Generating DB schema from model in Yii

Tags: orm, mapping, yii, symfony

Is there way to generate mysql schema from Yii model? In model i describe fields and relations. So it is enough to generate/update db structure. 
Like symfony 2 command line:

php console/app doctrine:schema:update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in yii a models attributes are dynamic and come from the database. Any properties defined in the model are not attributes and therefore not in the database. For this reason if you add a new column to the post table the Post model will automatically have a `magic` property of that column.

What I think you're after are [Migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration)

Comment: I need two-way migration. From db -> model. And from model to db. I'll explain. I have db schema in MySQL Workbench and after any changes (new fields, add FK etc) i need update models. It is ok with Gii. But after i have actually models i need update database on all servers from these models.

Comment: I know it's almost 4 years late but I see the sense in requiring something like this. It's similar to what Sequelize ORM (NodeJS) offers